# How to convert functional component into class component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

This is the functional component sample that I want to use.

> (https://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player/blob/dev/example/react/screens/PlaylistScreen.js)

How to convert this into class component?

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import TrackPlayer from "react-native-track-player";

import Player from "../components/Player";
import playlistData from "../data/playlist.json";
import localTrack from "../resources/pure.m4a";

export default function LandingScreen() {
  const playbackState = TrackPlayer.usePlaybackState();

  useEffect(() => {
    TrackPlayer.setupPlayer();
    TrackPlayer.updateOptions({
      stopWithApp: false,
      capabilities: [
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PLAY,
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PAUSE,
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_SKIP_TO_NEXT,
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS,
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_STOP
      ],
      compactCapabilities: [
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PLAY,
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PAUSE
      ]
    });
  }, []);

  async function togglePlayback() {
    const currentTrack = await TrackPlayer.getCurrentTrack();
    if (currentTrack == null) {
      await TrackPlayer.reset();
      await TrackPlayer.add(playlistData);
      await TrackPlayer.add({
        id: "local-track",
        url: localTrack,
        title: "Pure (Demo)",
        artist: "David Chavez",
        artwork: "https://picsum.photos/200"
      });
      await TrackPlayer.play();
    } else {
      if (playbackState === TrackPlayer.STATE_PAUSED) {
        await TrackPlayer.play();
      } else {
        await TrackPlayer.pause();
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.description}>
        We'll be inserting a playlist into the library loaded from
        `playlist.json`. We'll also be using the `ProgressComponent` which
        allows us to track playback time.
      </Text>
      <Player
        onNext={skipToNext}
        style={styles.player}
        onPrevious={skipToPrevious}
        onTogglePlayback={togglePlayback}
      />
      <Text style={styles.state}>{getStateName(playbackState)}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

LandingScreen.navigationOptions = {
  title: "Playlist Example"
};

function getStateName(state) {
  switch (state) {
    case TrackPlayer.STATE_NONE:
      return "None";
    case TrackPlayer.STATE_PLAYING:
      return "Playing";
    case TrackPlayer.STATE_PAUSED:
      return "Paused";
    case TrackPlayer.STATE_STOPPED:
      return "Stopped";
    case TrackPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING:
      return "Buffering";
  }
}

async function skipToNext() {
  try {
    await TrackPlayer.skipToNext();
  } catch (_) {}
}

async function skipToPrevious() {
  try {
    await TrackPlayer.skipToPrevious();
  } catch (_) {}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
  },
  description: {
    width: "80%",
    marginTop: 20,
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  player: {
    marginTop: 40
  },
  state: {
    marginTop: 20
  }
});
```

I tried as following. But it gives me error.

```
import React, { Component, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions, Image, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import Player from './Player'
import TrackPlayer from 'react-native-track-player';

// const playbackState = TrackPlayer.usePlaybackState();  // I don't know how to manage this.

export default class MusicPlayer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      full: true,
      clicked: '',
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    TrackPlayer.setupPlayer();
    TrackPlayer.updateOptions({
      stopWithApp: false,
      capabilities: [
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PLAY,
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PAUSE,
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_SKIP_TO_NEXT,
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS,
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_STOP
      ],
      compactCapabilities: [
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PLAY,
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PAUSE
      ]
    });
  }

  async togglePlayback() {
    const currentTrack = await TrackPlayer.getCurrentTrack();
    if (currentTrack == null) {
      await TrackPlayer.reset();
      await TrackPlayer.add(playlistData);
      await TrackPlayer.add({
        id: "local-track",
        url: 'http://192.168.22.27:8000/' + this.props.navigation.getParam('clickedSource'),
        title: "Pure (Demo)",
        artist: "David Chavez",
        artwork: "https://picsum.photos/200"
      });
      await TrackPlayer.play();
    } else {
      if (playbackState === TrackPlayer.STATE_PAUSED) {
        await TrackPlayer.play();
      } else {
        await TrackPlayer.pause();
      }
    }
  }

  async skipToNext() {
    try {
      await TrackPlayer.skipToNext();
    } catch (_) { }
  }

  async skipToPrevious() {
    try {
      await TrackPlayer.skipToPrevious();
    } catch (_) { }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container} >
        <Player
          onNext={()=>this.skipToNext()}
          style={styles.player}
          onPrevious={()=>this.skipToPrevious()}
          onTogglePlayback={()=>this.togglePlayback()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  player: {
    marginTop: 40
  },
});
```

How can I convert this into class component?

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: ya it will be easier to debug if we knew what error you are getting

Comment: Place in state `playbackState: TrackPlayer.usePlaybackState(),`, and reference as `this.state.playbackState` in `togglePlayback` handler.

Comment: Thank you Drew Reese. I tried with your method.
The error I get is :
Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1.  ..... 2. .... 3. ......   etc

Comment: Oof, yeah, I see now `usePlaybackState` appears to be a react hook (or named like one).

Comment: You: "reference as this.state.playbackState in togglePlayback handler."
How can I do this?  As I am beginner, so I don't know how to write this.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://react-native-kit.github.io/react-native-track-player/api/#player-information) you can use `TrackPlayer.getState`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`usePlaybackState` is a react hook, but it appears there exists a [getState](https://react-native-kit.github.io/react-native-track-player/documentation/#getstate) function that returns a promise. You don't want to store this state object as it likely will become stale very fast, so no need to use `this.playbackState` at all. You'll just need to await it each time you need to access the current player state.

```
const playbackState = await TrackPlayer.getState(); // <-- get player state
if (playbackState === TrackPlayer.STATE_PAUSED) {
  await TrackPlayer.play();
} else {
  await TrackPlayer.pause();
}
```

Full code

```
import React, { Component, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions, Image, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import Player from './Player'
import TrackPlayer from 'react-native-track-player';

export default class MusicPlayer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      full: true,
      clicked: '',
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    TrackPlayer.setupPlayer();
    TrackPlayer.updateOptions({
      stopWithApp: false,
      capabilities: [
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PLAY,
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PAUSE,
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_SKIP_TO_NEXT,
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS,
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_STOP
      ],
      compactCapabilities: [
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PLAY,
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PAUSE
      ]
    });
  }

  async togglePlayback() {
    const currentTrack = await TrackPlayer.getCurrentTrack();
    if (currentTrack == null) {
      await TrackPlayer.reset();
      await TrackPlayer.add(playlistData);
      await TrackPlayer.add({
        id: "local-track",
        url: 'http://192.168.22.27:8000/' + this.props.navigation.getParam('clickedSource'),
        title: "Pure (Demo)",
        artist: "David Chavez",
        artwork: "https://picsum.photos/200"
      });
      await TrackPlayer.play();
    } else {
      const playbackState = await TrackPlayer.getState(); // <-- get player state
      if (playbackState === TrackPlayer.STATE_PAUSED) {
        await TrackPlayer.play();
      } else {
        await TrackPlayer.pause();
      }
    }
  }

  async skipToNext() {
    try {
      await TrackPlayer.skipToNext();
    } catch (_) { }
  }

  async skipToPrevious() {
    try {
      await TrackPlayer.skipToPrevious();
    } catch (_) { }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container} >
        <Player
          onNext={()=>this.skipToNext()}
          style={styles.player}
          onPrevious={()=>this.skipToPrevious()}
          onTogglePlayback={()=>this.togglePlayback()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Then in the line3  there is <import Player from './Player'>.
This Player.js is also functional component.
Is it possible to important functional component into class component?  (Still same error)

Comment: You can import *any* react component for use in any other component. Just can't call react hooks outside a functional component, i.e. in class-based components.

Comment: Actually I chose this module to execute music in background of project.
Is there any good advice to execute background music? I mean another module or real full example.

Comment: Unfortunately no, my JS audio experience is a few years stale and involved [p5js](https://p5js.org/). Glad to help though.